# Sinon stub has weird behavior when used with mocha watch

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mocha.js, sinon

So here's the basic setup we have

`src/MyComponent.js`

```
import actions from `src/actions`

 export const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
      onClick: () => {
        dispatch(actions.myAction())
      }
    }
 }
```

`src/actions.js`

```
const actions = { 
  myAction: () => () => ...
}
export default actions
```

`src/MyComponentTest.js`

```
 import sinon from 'sinon'
 import actions from 'src/actions'
 import { mapDispatchToProps } from 'src/MyComponent'

 describe('onClickTests, () => {
   let dispatch = sinon.spy()
   let onClick

   beforeEach(() => {
     onClick = mapDispatchToProps(dispatch).onClick
   })

   it('calls dispatch with myAction', () => {
     function f () {}
     sinon.stub(actions, 'myAction').returns(f)
     onClick()
     expect(dispatch.args[0]).to.deep.equal([f])
   })
 })
```

Basically, we're checking that the `onClick` function is calling `dispatch` with the return value of `actions.myAction`. Since the real `actions.myAction` returns an anonymous function, we're stubbing it to return the function `f`. When we run this with Mocha everything works, until we run with `--watch`. The first run still passes as expected, but when we save a test and the tests are re-run, this tests fails with

```
expected [ [Function: f] ] to deeply equal [ [Function: f] ]
```

If I made these changes to the test

```
   it('calls dispatch with myAction', () => {
     function f () {}
     sinon.stub(actions, 'myAction').returns(2)
     onClick()
     expect(dispatch.args[0]).to.deep.equal([2])
   })
```

I get

```
expected [ [Function: f] ] to deeply equal [ [2] ]
```

So what I gather from this is that on the second run, the `f` that `actions.minimize` returned was the "old" `f` from the first run. We've tried a wide variety of different variations on this like using `module.exports/require` instead of `export/import` and moving things around into Mocha hooks (`beforeEach`, etc) and nothing seems to be working, which leads me to believe this is a more fundamental issue with how we're testing. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've faced this issue before and it took a while to figure it out.

Not sure if that's your case, but I was using `.jsx` extensions for my components and turns out this brings all sorts of random problems.

Renaming `Component.jsx` to `Component.js` solved it.